# How to prevent browser's download prompt for certain type of files

Tags: javascript, file

I have an `XMLHttpRequest` where I send a file to the server. The server validates the file and then sends back a response.

Upon receiving the response, I want to show a preview of the uploaded file (only one per request), *only if that's allowed* (like pdfs and images), while for all other type of files I just want to show an alert stating that no preview is available.

This is my `onload` function where I basically create an `object` element and set its `data` attribute to the file's Blob I create on the fly:

```
xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        // do preliminary stuff
        ...

        // show preview
        let target = document.getElementById('RightContentPreview')
        target.replaceChildren();
        let previewUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        let previewEl = document.createElement('object');
        previewEl.setAttribute('data', previewUrl);
        previewEl.setAttribute('type', 'application/pdf');
        target.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', previewEl);
        target.classList.add('show', 'active');
    } else {
        // deal with errors
    }
}
```

I see that the browser does that automatically, but for those type of files where a preview isn't available, I get prompted with a 'Save As' dialog. Is there a way to prevent this from happening without going throug the file MIME type?

Comment: @KJ you're totally right, I was so focused in my train of thoughts that I lost the big picture... Instead of sending to server now I just use the input file as the data source for the preview, thanks. BTW, the automatic prompt still remains, ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get around that prompt by setting the download attribute.
Something like this, although not tested:

```
xhr.onload = function () {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    // do preliminary stuff
    // ...

    // show preview
    let target = document.getElementById('RightContentPreview');
    target.replaceChildren();
    let previewUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    let previewEl = document.createElement('object');
    if (isPreviewAllowed(file.type)) {
      previewEl.setAttribute('data', previewUrl);
      previewEl.setAttribute('type', 'application/pdf');
    } else {
      previewEl.setAttribute('data', previewUrl);
      previewEl.setAttribute('download', 'true'); // Add download attribute
    }
    target.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', previewEl);
    target.classList.add('show', 'active');
  } else {
    // deal with errors
  }
}

function isPreviewAllowed(fileType) {
  // Check if the file type is allowed for preview (e.g., PDF or image types)
  return fileType.startsWith('image/') || fileType === 'application/pdf';
}
```

Comment: Isn't the download attribute a property for `HTMLAnchorElement` that is used to download files? I mean, that's what I'm trying to prevent...

Comment: What if you don't do anything if `isPreviewAllowed` returns false?